# Javascript global array undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I'm having problems with this javascript code, second alert of (tracking_data) throws 'undefined' like if the variable was deleted or cleared and I don't see any part of the code doing that. I hope you can help me with this. Regards.

```
var track_id = '';      // Name/ID of the exercise
var watch_id = null;    // ID of the geolocation
var tracking_data = []; // Array containing GPS position objects

$("#startTracking_start").live('click', function () {

// Start tracking the User
watch_id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(

    // Success
    function (position) {
        tracking_data.push(position);
        alert(tracking_data);
    },

    // Error
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    },

    // Settings
        {frequency: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

    // Tidy up the UI
    track_id = $("#track_id").val();

    $("#track_id").hide();

    $("#startTracking_status").html("Tracking workout: <strong>" + track_id + "</strong>");
});


$("#startTracking_stop").live('click', function(){
    alert(tracking_data);

// Stop tracking the user
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watch_id);

// Save the tracking data
window.localStorage.setItem(track_id, JSON.stringify(tracking_data));

// Reset watch_id and tracking_data 
var watch_id = null;
var tracking_data = null;

// Tidy up the UI
$("#track_id").val("").show();

$("#startTracking_status").html("Stopped tracking workout: <strong>" + track_id + "    </strong>");

});
```

Comment: did you try alerting position? it's probably undefined.

Comment: @kennypu the code is pushing data into the array, but when I try to read it from the other function it give me 'undefined' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to hoisting, all var declarations are moved to the top of it's enclosing function. In other words, you're overriding `tracking_data` inside your function.

Changing from `var tracking_data = null;` (inside your function) to `tracking_data = null;` will solve your problem.

The example below reproduces this behaviour:

```
var v1 = 'hello';
(function(){
  console.log(v1); //prints hello
  v1 = 'hi';
  console.log(v1); //prints hi
})()
```

.

```
var v2 = 'hello';
(function(){
  console.log(v2); //prints undefined. Due to hoisting the var v2 was overriden inside this scope. 
  var v2 = 'hi';
  console.log(v2); //prints hi
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `var tracking_data = null`, you make `tracking_data` local to the click callback. It's not the same `tracking_data` from the outer scope. Due to JavaScript's variable and function hoisting, the variable declaration is done at the very beginning of the function, which will set `tracking_data` to `undefined`.

Get rid of `var` and on that line (and the line before it) and your code should work as intended.